# Using expire_on_commit with autocommit in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, autocommit

For various reasons, I've configured my sessionmaker with `autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=True`. Mainly, I just want autocommit behavior. The other flags are set due the warning in the SQLAlchemy docs:

> In the absense of a demarcated transaction, the Session cannot make appropriate decisions as to when autoflush should occur nor when auto-expiration should occur, so these features should be disabled with autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False.
>
> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#autocommit-mode

Without the `expire_on_commit` behavior, I often find myself having to expire objects manually so it would be nice to use `expire_on_commit=True`. My question is, is this warning still accurate? `expire_on_commit` makes it sound pretty clear when something expires so I don't know if it agrees with the documentation.